# Best way to deal with assets in Rails with AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I'm using AWS and Cloudfront to serve my assets. The thing is, my css and js files are stored locally. Images and videos are on AWS Bucket.

I'm about to start it all again, and since I'm pretty new to rails, I was wondering what would be the best way to deal with this.

I looked around, found several options:
- Creating specific behaviors so that I can use local css and js, and AWS-stored images
- Uploading everything on AWS and then use Cloudfront (my personal favourite, seems like the best option to me)
- Other options ?

Id anyone used AWS to serve assets with RoR, what is your opinion? And do you use any particular gem to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your Cloudfront distribution's origin to the url of your production rails app, Cloudfront will pull any files that it does not already have cached from there when they are requested by a browser.

In your rails app, you should set your asset host to the url of your Cloudfront distribution. Here's an example:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.action_controller.asset_host = "<YOUR DISTRIBUTION SUBDOMAIN>.cloudfront.net"
```

This will tell rails to link to the asset, but do it through the Cloudfront URL. This means for every asset you have, cloudfront will only request it once per version. Whenever you release an update, the url to the new asset will be different which will cause Cloudfront to grab it since it's not already cached.

Using this method prevents you from having to sync your files to s3 upon each deploy.